# logs of run command in ssm are not going to s3 bucket. what permissions are required for getting the logs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

logs of run command in ssm are not going to s3 bucket. what permissions are required for getting the logs. These permissions should be as part of ssmmaintainancewindow role or role attached to the EC2 instance.